# Clojure Speclj with-redefs and a stub from a different thread

Tags: java, clojure, bdd, speclj

I'm testing a function to make sure that it calls a function that's in another namespace. I'd like to stub the function out (using [speclj stub](http://speclj.com/docs/stub)), so I can record the invocations.

```
(defn fn-under-test []
  (p/helper-fn))

(describe "test"
  (with-stubs)
  (around [it]
    (with-redefs [p/helper-fn (stub :helper)]
      (it)))
  (it "should call the helper-fn"
    (fn-under-test)
    (should-have-invoked :helper {:times 1})))
```

I get an exception:

```
java.lang.Exception: Stub recoding not bound.  Please add (with-stubs) to the decribe/context.
```

If `helper-fn` is defined in the current namespace, everything works as expected. How can I stub a function in another namespace using speclj?

EDIT: The exception occurs when the stubbed function is called from a different thread. I created a [pull request](https://github.com/slagyr/speclj/pull/114) that fixes the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I coded up your example and the specs ran fine; passed without error.  I can't think of a reason stubbing fns in a another namespace wouldn't work.  I do it all the time.

Here's a gist showing my work:  https://gist.github.com/slagyr/2aed1ccfd8ec702d7051

Comment: Oops - my mistake. The problem occurs when the test is happening in a separate thread (e.g., testing a REST server). I'll update the question.

Comment: Rather than completely changing my question here, I'll move this issue along with a pull request to the speclj github repo. Thanks for the help, @slagyr!